# Onomatopoeia for a long, intense scream - "AAAAA!!"

Tags: manga, onomatopoeia

How could you describe a very long, very intense scream - one that expresses extreme anger or pain? So far I've only been able to find examples of short gasps, or screams with happier connotations.

In particular I'm looking for the equivalent of reading the word [*"AAAAAAAAAAAAA!!"* in a comic strip](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ed9osQUWsAQWYK7.jpg), which can be stretched out as long as you like by adding more A's. Does Japanese have a version that can also be infinitely-repeated like that?

Comment: Often these appear as twiddles "a~~~~~~", I believe.

Answer (score 1):

One option that’s rather difficult to type in  normal font is あ゙ (あ with ゛ (dakuten)). Although not an official letter, it’s been used in manga to express approximately the effect you are looking for. [Wikipedia](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%82%99)